ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable In selenium - Java
I have a translation modal page, where i am trying to translate a particular text, The english translation of the text is displayed in the first row, and the pointer events are not allowed (ie pointer-events: none) for the select element in that row, now using selenium i am adding a new row and the pointer events are allowed in the new row, and based on this style, i am trying to click an ion-select element. But I am getting ElementNotInteractableException. The same code is working in another scenerio. Why this inconsistency?
This is my html code
             <ion-select [ngClass]="obj.lang == 'en' ? 'pointer-none' : ''" class="select-lang"
                        interface="popover" [name]="'languages' + j" placeholder="Language" [(ngModel)]="obj.lang"
                        [ngStyle]="{'pointer-events' : obj.readOnly ? 'none' : 'all'}"  id={{j}}
                        (ionChange)="getTranslation(translationWrapper.translationData, obj, $event, j)">

                        <ion-select-option *ngFor="let language of getAvailableLanguages(j, obj.lang)"
                          [value]="language.categoryCode">
                          {{ language.categoryDisplayText }}
                        </ion-select-option>
                      </ion-select>

 // Step 3:  Find the newly added row (assuming it is the lastion-select-option) 
    WebElement clickableElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ion-select[@style='pointer-events: all;']")); 
    Thread.sleep(2000); // Wait for language dropdown to appear            
    clickableElement.click(); 

In the above code, I am trying to click an ion-select element whose style="pointer-events:all". But I am getting ElementNotInteractableException.

Did you try waiting for clickable using a WebDriverWait? My guess is that your locator is either incorrect or is finding more than one element and the first element is hidden or otherwise not interactable. Can you share the URL?

Also, the HTML should be the rendered HTML on the page after it's loaded. That looks like HTML source.
